# jQuery backgroundPosition css sprites not working together?

Tags: jquery, css, sprite, background-position

I have started making a web portfolio for my photos I'm not a web designer it just interests me. Here is the page : http://jsfiddle.net/RhjJZ/1/ in jsfiddle.
I made CSS sprites to make background for the `<a>` links. I want them to change when the mouse is over them so I made that script with jQuery and it does seem to work, I can't imagine why, tried in a lot of different ways... searched a lot of similar problems on the Internet but they couldn't help me out. If someone pointed out what I did wrong I would be very glad! and my picture for the menu is a 1x296 px one.

Comment: Where is the `val` parameter coming from?

Comment: onmouseover() from HTML.

Comment: Can you add a `menu.png` to the fiddle?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/menufc.png/ here is the picture and added here too http://jsfiddle.net/RhjJZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `menu()` function is not in the normal scope because of jQuery, so you get the Javascript error: `menu(xx) is not a function`.

The solution is to set those hard-coded values using the `data-` prefix attribute scheme and then handle the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header id="menu">
            <h1>dawe's portfolio</h1>

        <nav>   <a id="m_portf" data-one="0" data-two="-37" href="#portfolio"
            width="1px">portfolio</a>
    <a id="m_music" data-one="-72" data-two="-111"
            href="#music">music</a>
    <a id="m_about" data-one="-148" data-two="-185"
            href="#about">about</a>
    <a id="m_contact" data-one="-222" data-two="-259"
            href="#contact">contact</a>

        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).animate({'background-position': '0px ' +$(this).attr('data-one')+'px';}, 1500);
});

$('a').on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).animate({'background-position': '0px ' +$(this).attr('data-two')+'px';}, 1500);
});
```

Comment: so I have to write mouseover and mouseout detection in jquery for every '<a id="...">' separately?

Comment: I accidentally pasted the wrong javascript. To answer your question, no.

Comment: No problem! You may want to add an if statement that checks if the a has a `data-` attribute first also.

Comment: I might be very shallow, but this does not work for me..copy pasted your script and html but nothing happens when i move the cursor over the '<a>'s...:S

Comment: Try it now. The `'background-position'` was `backgroundPosition` in your code.

Comment: still nothing happens, I am pretty sure it should work because I made another version without jQuery which does not move smoothly which is not animated, only moved there where it should be.